# how to set an enum in struct to use as an identifier to init a custom object

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set a custom enum for my structs to use to be able to identify themselves once I put them all into the same array. I made my structs conform to the same protocol so that I didn't have to use Any/AnyObject but now I am having trouble on the proper way to set the enum inside the struct and creating a function to turn the object back to its original state after.

I currently have all of my structs in one array by conforming them all to the same protocol

```
struct Artist: Decodable, ContentWrapper {
    let name: String
    let image: [[String:String]]

    init(name: String, image: [[String:String]]) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }        
}

struct Album: Decodable, ContentWrapper {
    let name: String
    let artist: String
    let image: [[String:String]]

    init(name: String, artist: String, image: [[String:String]]) {
        self.name = name
        self.artist = artist
        self.image = image
    }
}

enum myType {
    case type(String)        
}


protocol ContentWrapper {
}
```

I need to set an enum for each struct to be able to identify themself and then be able to have a function to return them to their original object after receiving them from an array.

Comment: Why not put the identification around your objects? `enum ContentWrapper { case artist(Artist) case album(Album)` and then create an array `[ContentWrapper]`?

Comment: That also works but how could i retrieve the item back from the array? It would still be in the form of the enum

Answer (score 1):

The tool you wanted to use here is an enum to hold the data, not an enum to hold the type. Get rid of `ContentWrapper` entirely and replace it with this:

```
enum Element {
    case artist(Artist)
    case album(Album)
}

var elements: [Element] = []
```

Now `elements` is an array of "artists or albums" which I believe is what you're looking for. The way you say "type or other type" in Swift is with an enum.

To deal with different element types, generally you'll use `switch`:

```
for element in elements {
    switch element {
    case .artist(let artist):
        // Perform "artist-like" functions on `artist`
        break
    case .album(let album):
        // Perform "album-like" functions on `album`
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. How could I receive the original element from the new array however?

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with a protocol, both `Album` and `Artist` must have something is the same, and I'm guessing that's the `type` you mentioned. So maybe you can just a property `type` in the protocol and implement in `Album` and `Artist`. Then you declare an array the `[ContentWrapper]`.

```swift
protocol ContentWrapper {
    var type: String { get }
}

extension ContentWrapper where Self == Artist {
    var type: String {
        return "Artist"
    }
}

extension ContentWrapper where Self == Album {
    var type: String {
        return "Album"
    }
}

var artist = Artist(name: "Ed Sheeran", image: [])
var album = Album(name: "Loose Change", artist: "Ed Sheeran", image: [])

let array: [ContentWrapper] = [artist, album]
for item in array {
    print("identifier: \(item.type)")
}

// Output:
// identifier: Artist
// identifier: Album
```